# Install from USB shows blinking cursor

Tags: nvidia, usb-drive

Tried installing Ubuntu 16 (32bit) on an old PC I have (atom 330, 2gb, 1.6hz, Nvidia ION)
Tried with 2 different USB sticks I get the same thing, booting from the USB doesn't load the installer, just shows me a blank screen with the blinking cursor top left. 
Not sure it's relevant but the video driver is Nvidia ION.

Comment: Try with nomodeset.

Comment: Well, usually in the same "Try Ubuntu..." menu you can use F6 to select nomodeset and other special modes. If you don't get to this menu then you have a problem with the way you created the installation media or the media itself. Plus, Atom 330 is a 64-bit CPU. You should try 64-bit and preferably create the USB flash with MKUSB (Ubuntu) or Rufus with MBR option (Windows). Also make sure you're using the latest 16.04.1.

Comment: What Nvidia model exactly?

Comment: Oh, that makes a whole lot of difference. ION is particularly tricky because, according to Nvidia, in Linux it should work with driver 340.96 and this version only. Anyway, the purpose of *nomodeset* is to work around this peculiar cases that have no support with the default open source driver (*nouveau*). "No Mode Set" loads a generic VESA driver that works anywhere (limited options of low resolutions). You need this setting when booting the installer *and* when running the installed system until you install Nvidia 340 (available on the official repositories).

Comment: Please edit your answer and add the info about Nvidia ION. Then I can write a complete guide as an answer. Comments are limited in space and formating options.

Comment: So the funny thing happened. I tried again and it worked flawlessly. probably a corrupt ISO or something. In any case the ION drivers probably fit the new 16.04 version. Tnx anyway.